# Passing data from table view to view controller

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

i am do a function when i click on the row and then will go to another view controller to show the detail but it's get an error

this is the error => **fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**

this is my code on table view didselectRow

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let popup = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "popUp") as! PopupViewController
    let pro_name = preCakeArray[indexPath.row]["pro_name"]
    popup.popUpTitle.text = pro_name as? String
    self.addChildViewController(popup)
    popup.view.frame =  self.view.bounds
    self.view.addSubview(popup.view)
    popup.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    }
```

and this is my ViewController to show the detail like popup

```
class PopupViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var popUpImg: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var popUpTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var popUpDes: UILabel!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
        }

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@IBAction func closeBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    self.view.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Comment: In which line you are getting exception?

Comment: Why are you adding `addChildViewController` and `self.view.addSubview(popup.view)` ? I think you are pushing somewhere so there is no need of doing this/

Comment: @AnuragSharma this line >> popup.popUpTitle.text = pro_name as? String

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1**

You can't set label text while addChildViewController or you need to pass string to viewcontroller and set that string to label .

```
class PopupViewController: UIViewController {

 var strPopTitle: String?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
        self.popUpTitle.text = strPopTitle
        }
```