# Unable to get text to appear in label. I can see the text in the console but I get an error that says Nil

Tags: swift3

I am passing data from one view controller to another. If I print the text to the console it will show. However when I try to add the text to my label on the view controller I get an error about Nil being found when unwrapping the optional.

Here is my code from the initial View Controller

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let selectedLady = DataService.instance.getLadies()[indexPath.row]
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "LadyView", sender: selectedLady)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let ladyView = segue.destination as? LadyView {
            assert(sender as? Lady != nil)
            ladyView.initLadies(selectedLady: sender as! Lady)
            //ladyView.selectedLadyName = selectedLady["name"]

        }
    }
```

And this is the code that is waiting in the second controller

```
func initLadies(selectedLady: Lady) {
    print(selectedLady.name)
    //This is the line that says it's Nil
    LadyName.text = selectedLadyName
}
```

This is my lady struct

```
struct Lady {
    private(set) public var name: String
    private(set) public var imageName: String
    private(set) public var subTitle: String
    private(set) public var body: String

    init(name: String, imageName: String, subTitle: String, body: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.imageName = imageName
        self.subTitle = subTitle
        self.body = body
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

I have looked at the other answer in this post [Passing data from table view to view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44323291/passing-data-from-table-view-to-view-controller) and although it's similar his answer seems to be slightly different.

Comment: update with Lady class also

Comment: I updated my code

Comment: remove initLadies method and just create a property selectedLady : Lady in second viewcontroller and then in viewdidload just try to     print(selectedLady.name) using if let and then it should work , nothing wrong with your code , try it

Comment: What do I pass in from the first controller? How do I make sure that the information is passed in?

Comment: did u try what i told you , just try once

Answer (score 0):

func initLadies(selectedLady: Lady) {

```
print(selectedLady.name)
LadyName.text = selectedLadyName.name
```

}

try this @CL Maciel